# Does using the filter command to exclude some values work with lm in r?

Tags: r, filter, lm

I am new to r. I am attempting a simple bivariate regression. My understanding is that I need the DV to be an interval level variable and so I am using the filter command to exclude a -1 from the integers. This leaves me with values 1 through to 7. What I'm unsure of is if using the filter command is a good way to do this for purposes of running lm.  I have named the regression reg.

In the elements of the lm, I can see na.action, which I am understanding as showing me there are 10 excluded rows of data. Am I understanding this correctly?

```
reg[["na.action"]]
133  252  352  408  700 1339 1392 1607 1623 1967 
133  252  352  408  700 1339 1392 1607 1623 1967 
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
```

Comment: I am not sure about your question. `na.action` removes NAs from your data (given your default `na.option`, equivalent to do `na.omit(data)`), both from your dependent variable and covariates.You see the rows where you have at least one NA. It has nothing to do with filtering -1 values.

Comment: @linog Thank you for clarifying the na.action element. What I want to check is that the values that I have filtered out - which are -1s in the data frame - are excluded from the lm. Is there a way of finding this out? Or put another way, can I find out the scalar values which are being included?

Comment: Ok I then proposed you an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## na.action

`na.action` removes NAs from your data (given your default `na.option`, equivalent to do `na.omit(data)`), both from your dependent variable and covariates.You see the rows where you have at least one NA.

## is there -1 values ?

You can check the elements that have been used to fit your model in the `$model` part of your `lm` object.

```r
ols <- lm(
  Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width,
  data = iris
)
head(ols$model)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
1          5.1         3.5
2          4.9         3.0
3          4.7         3.2
4          4.6         3.1
5          5.0         3.6
6          5.4         3.9
```

That's the model frame you get after removing NAs and other operations necessary to construct the `X` matrix. If you want to check the precense of -1 values in your `y` vector, you can do

```r
which(ols$model$y == -1)
```

Assuming your variable is named `y`

Comment: the which command you explain is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!